# angular2 ng2d3 functionality is missing?

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts, bar-chart, linechart

I'm working with ng2d3 to display data into charts.
But i've got 2 issues working with this library:

1. the linechart on https://swimlane.github.io/ng2d3/ offers a timeline which seems not to work - any documentation or best practices there? the space for the timeline is just empty after rendering. How do i display this timeline beyond the chart?
2. the charts in the showroom can be set to div-size by clicking on "Dimensions > Fit Container" but in my project they always expect `view: any[] = [600, 400];` to offer a px size. How can i change that?

Answer (score 0):

Creator of the library here.

1 - The timeline feature on line and area charts only works when you have a time data for your x-scale, i.e. the name property of your values are date objects:

```
[
  {
    name: new Date(),
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: new Date(),
    value: 10
  },
}
```

2 - If you remove the view input from the chart, or set it to undefined, the chart will automatically fit its parent container.